# How to access the token created by iOS Stripe?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

i successfully  got generating tokens working on the ios side, and i have a heroku rails app set up. How do i retrieve this token on the server side?

getting the error `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/login_controller.rb:11:in 'log_in'`

here is my controller code:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def log_in
    puts params

    headers = {"X-Parse-Application-Id" => "APIKEY", 
                         "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => "APIKEY"}
    query = {:username => params[:user][:username], 
                     :password => params[:user][:password]}

            @response = HTTParty.get('https://api.parse.com/1/login', 
        :query => query,
            :headers => headers)

        session[:session_token] = @response["sessionToken"]
        session[:object_id] = @response["objectId"]
        @object_id = session[:object_id]
            @test = HTTParty.get("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/#{@object_id}", 
                :headers => {"X-Parse-Application-Id" => "APIKEY", 
                             "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" =>"APIKEY"} )

        session[:stripe_acct_id] = @test["uid"]


end
    def logout
        logout = HTTParty.post('https://api.parse.com/1/logout',
          :headers => {"X-Parse-Application-Id" => "APIKEY", 
                       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => "APIKEY",
                       "X-Parse-Session-Token" => session[:session_token]})
        reset_session
                redirect_to :controller => "login"

end

    def deauthorize

      @object_id = session[:object_id]

           HTTParty.post("https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/deauthorize",
                    :basic_auth => { :username => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET'] },
                    :query => { client_id: ENV['STRIPE_CONNECT_CLIENT_ID'],
                                stripe_user_id: session[:stripe_acct_id]})

    end
end
```

Comment: You use StripeJS or Checkout ?

Comment: i havent implemented either, i am using Stripe Connect

Comment: i just ran `heroku logs` and i see that the token was received but after the params of the token, it says `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

Comment: Add protect_from_forgery: :null for you méthod in your controller

Comment: also you can skip verification only on specific action `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: :my_unprotected_action`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller add:

```
protect_from_forgery: :null, only: :log_in
```

For your error, it's because you don't send user object in your post request.

Comment: also how do i retrieve the token where i can put it in a variable or something

Comment: Inspect your params, normaly param[:stripeToken] :)

Comment: i did, and its not coming up when i do `params.inspect`

Comment: Just puts your params and add your input params

Comment: theres no token for some reason, but i get this when i send it https://gist.github.com/farhansyed9/7492abd837ce28ab80d9

Comment: i fixed the CSRF issue i had. 
`Started POST "/login/log_in" for ::1 at 2015-08-14 13:05:08 -0700
Processing by LoginController#log_in as */*
  Parameters: {"stripeToken"=>"tok_16ZoQK27so3cCAuPJ5K06P7y"}
{"stripeToken"=>"tok_16ZoQK27so3cCAuPJ5K06P7y", "controller"=>"login", "action"=>"log_in"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/login_controller.rb:11:in `log_in'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87038/discussion-between-gearnode-and-user3670235).